# Trouble with JQuery for multi-level dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been working on the nav menu for a website that should have multiple levels. I'm having trouble with the JQuery in terms of having the correct drop downs appear on click. I'm new to using Javascript and Jquery in webpages so I appreciate any help I can get. This is what I have so far.

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

#main-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#main-bar>li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px 80px;
}

#main-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#product-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -81px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#product-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

#product-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#clarinet-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -71px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#clarinet-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 30px 0 35px;
}

#clarinet-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#saxophone-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -183px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#saxophone-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 16px;
}

#saxophone-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#flute-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -314px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#flute-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 110px;
}

#flute-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#oboe-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -372px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#oboe-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 75px;
}

#oboe-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bassoon-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -456px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#bassoon-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 70px 0 300px;
}

#bassoon-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#recorder-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -560px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#recorder-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 38px;
}

#recorder-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#brass-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -669px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#brass-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 19px 0 15px;
}

#brass-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#guitar-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -755px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#guitar-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 90px;
}

#guitar-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#piano-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -846px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#piano-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 70px 0 320px;
}

#piano-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#orchestral-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -932px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#orchestral-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 125px 0 115px;
}

#piano-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#percussion-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -1049px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#percussion-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 80px 0 70px;
}

#percussion-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="main-bar">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Product</a>
      <ul id="product-bar" class="sub-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="test">Clarinet</a>
          <ul id="clarinet-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bb Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Eb Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabass Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contra-Alto Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Basset Horn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Saxophone</a>
          <ul id="saxophone-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Alto Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Baritone Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soprano Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sopranino Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabass Saxophone</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Flute</a>
          <ul id="flute-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Oboe</a>
          <ul id="oboe-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oboe D'amore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">English Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo Oboe</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Bassoon</a>
          <ul id="bassoon-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bassoon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabassoon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Recorder</a>
          <ul id="recorder-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Alto Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soprano Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Great Bass Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo Recorder</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Brass</a>
          <ul id="brass-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trumpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trombone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cornet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">French Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tuba</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flugelhorn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Euphonium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mellophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Baritone Horn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Guitar</a>
          <ul id="guitar-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Electic Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acoustic Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Classical Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Guitar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Piano</a>
          <ul id="piano-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Piano</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Keyboard</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Orchestral</a>
          <ul id="orchestral-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Violin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Viola</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Percussion</a>
          <ul id="percussion-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Keyboard Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mallet Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marching Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">General Percussion</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--closes product-bar-->
    </li>
    <!--closes product list item that is holding all the products-->
    <li><a href="#">Shop By Brands</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How to Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quick Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--closes main-bar-->
</nav>
```

Comment: `$(this).find('.sub-menu').get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo, though CSS needs to be fixed. It was a simple JQuery code, instead of `toggleClass()`, we needed to use `children` as there are nested menus:

```js
$('.dropdown a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
    ullist.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

#main-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#main-bar>li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px 80px;
}

#main-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#product-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -81px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#product-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

#product-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#clarinet-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -71px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#clarinet-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 30px 0 35px;
}

#clarinet-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#saxophone-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -183px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#saxophone-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 16px;
}

#saxophone-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#flute-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -314px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#flute-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 110px;
}

#flute-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#oboe-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -372px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#oboe-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 75px;
}

#oboe-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bassoon-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -456px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#bassoon-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 70px 0 300px;
}

#bassoon-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#recorder-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -560px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#recorder-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 38px;
}

#recorder-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#brass-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -669px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#brass-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 19px 0 15px;
}

#brass-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#guitar-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -755px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#guitar-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 90px;
}

#guitar-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#piano-bar {
  //position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -846px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#piano-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 70px 0 320px;
}

#piano-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#orchestral-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -932px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#orchestral-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 125px 0 115px;
}

#piano-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#percussion-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -1049px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#percussion-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 80px 0 70px;
}

#percussion-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="main-bar">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Product</a>
      <ul id="product-bar" class="sub-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="test">Clarinet</a>
          <ul id="clarinet-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bb Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Eb Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabass Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contra-Alto Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Basset Horn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Saxophone</a>
          <ul id="saxophone-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Alto Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Baritone Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soprano Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sopranino Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabass Saxophone</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Flute</a>
          <ul id="flute-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Oboe</a>
          <ul id="oboe-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oboe D'amore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">English Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo Oboe</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Bassoon</a>
          <ul id="bassoon-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bassoon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabassoon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Recorder</a>
          <ul id="recorder-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Alto Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soprano Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Great Bass Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo Recorder</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Brass</a>
          <ul id="brass-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trumpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trombone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cornet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">French Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tuba</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flugelhorn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Euphonium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mellophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Baritone Horn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Guitar</a>
          <ul id="guitar-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Electic Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acoustic Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Classical Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Guitar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Piano</a>
          <ul id="piano-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Piano</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Keyboard</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Orchestral</a>
          <ul id="orchestral-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Violin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Viola</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Percussion</a>
          <ul id="percussion-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Keyboard Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mallet Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marching Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">General Percussion</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--closes product-bar-->
    </li>
    <!--closes product list item that is holding all the products-->
    <li><a href="#">Shop By Brands</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How to Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quick Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--closes main-bar-->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I added the JQuery code you provided and in theory it works the way I want it to. When I click on an instrument within products, the dropdown appears directly below the product bar. But now it seems that if I click on one instrument and then click on a second instrument, the second instrument's dropdown overlaps the first instrument's dropdown as opposed to replacing it. For something like this, would it be best to create a separate function for this desired effect or add to the existing function?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for your problem is that the submenu tags not only have the class `.sub-menu` which is addressed you your jQuery, but they also have IDs, and the CSS rules for these IDs contain `display: none` which has more specifity that a class. So in order to overwrite that you either can use `!important` on your `.show` class (which is not that good)…

```
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

…or (better) remove the `display: block` from the CSS rules for those IDs (`saxophone-bar` , `flute-bar` etc.)