# Need help hiding ul's - JQuery

Tags: jquery, navbar, dropdown

I've been working on a multi-level dropdown for some time now. I'm having trouble, displaying it the way I would like. Once the dropdown link is clicked on, the submenu should appear directly below the main menu bar. The problem is that if I click on one product link, and then click on another product link, the second link's corresponding ul just hovers over the first one as opposed to replacing it. I'm very new to JQuery and am not sure where to go from here.This is what I have so far.

```js
$('.dropdown a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ullist =
    $(this).parent().children('ul:first');

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

#main-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#main-bar>li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px 80px;
}

#main-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#product-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -81px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#product-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

#product-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#clarinet-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -71px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#clarinet-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 30px 0 35px;
}

#clarinet-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#saxophone-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -183px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#saxophone-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 16px;
}

#saxophone-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#flute-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -314px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#flute-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 110px;
}

#flute-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#oboe-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -372px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#oboe-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 75px;
}

#oboe-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bassoon-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -456px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#bassoon-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 70px 0 300px;
}

#bassoon-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#recorder-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -560px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#recorder-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 38px;
}

#recorder-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#brass-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -669px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#brass-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 19px 0 15px;
}

#brass-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#guitar-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -755px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#guitar-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 90px;
}

#guitar-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#piano-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -846px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#piano-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 70px 0 320px;
}

#piano-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#orchestral-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -932px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#orchestral-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 125px 0 115px;
}

#piano-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#percussion-bar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -1049px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

#percussion-bar>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 80px 0 70px;
}

#percussion-bar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="main-bar">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Product</a>
      <!--sub-menu will hold all contents in dropdown --list items-->
      <ul id="product-bar" class="sub-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="test">Clarinet</a>
          <ul id="clarinet-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bb Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Eb Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabass Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contra-Alto Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Basset Horn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Saxophone</a>
          <ul id="saxophone-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Alto Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Baritone Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soprano Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sopranino Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Saxophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabass Saxophone</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Flute</a>
          <ul id="flute-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Oboe</a>
          <ul id="oboe-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oboe D'amore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">English Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo Oboe</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Bassoon</a>
          <ul id="bassoon-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bassoon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contrabassoon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Recorder</a>
          <ul id="recorder-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Alto Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soprano Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Great Bass Recorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Piccolo Recorder</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Brass</a>
          <ul id="brass-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trumpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trombone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cornet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">French Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tuba</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flugelhorn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Euphonium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mellophone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alto Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenor Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Baritone Horn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Guitar</a>
          <ul id="guitar-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Electic Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acoustic Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Classical Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass Guitar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Piano</a>
          <ul id="piano-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Piano</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Keyboard</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Orchestral</a>
          <ul id="orchestral-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Violin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Viola</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bass</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Percussion</a>
          <ul id="percussion-bar" class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Keyboard Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mallet Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marching Percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">General Percussion</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--closes product-bar-->
    </li>
    <!--closes product list item that is holding all the products-->
    <li><a href="#">Shop By Brands</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How to Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quick Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--closes main-bar-->
</nav>
```

Comment: where did you get your `.dropdown` class?

Comment: it's the class name for the li's that are parents of ul sub menus

Comment: So, you want to hide/show the li's on .dropdown click?

Comment: I want to hide/show .dropdown > ul. So for example, if I click on products, the products dropdown will appear. If I click on clarinet, within products, then the clarinet dropdown will appear below the products dropdown. But, if I then clicked on saxophone, within products, then saxophone's dropdown appears over clarinet's dropdown. As opposed to saxophone replacing clarinet's dropdown. I hope that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with JQuery for multi-level dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128877/trouble-with-jquery-for-multi-level-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.dropdown a').on('click', function(e) {

    if($(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next('ul').hide();
    } else {
        $('ul#main-bar').find('li.dropdown').each(function() {
            $(this).find('ul:first').hide();
        });
        $(this).next('ul').show();
    }

});
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it. The product's drop down appears but when you click on any of the instrument links, their dropdown does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to toggle the siblings. try this.

```
$('.dropdown a').click(function(event){

    $(this).next().toggle();

});
```